# web/screen scrape product reviews online with bazaarvoice/bv as source?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Here is an example: http://www.t-mobile.com/cell-phones/samsung-galaxy-note-4.html

It is using bazaarvoice/bv as the review generator. It is also using javascript/ajax to load the different pages, so I can't simply download 1 html source file. Ideally, I would like to have 1 large html file (parsed or not don't care) with every single review info

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm new to this web-scraping & screen-scraping

Answer (score 0):

Yes actually there is a github repository for this.  Here is a link to the website: http://webscraper.io/.  Download it and run with with Chrome.  Watch the videos.  It is a handy tool.

Comment: interesting concept and tool, but doesn't work. it doesn't seem to like the javascript/ajax and the way the reviews are being pushed from bazaarvoice. help?

Comment: What data on that page are you trying to pull?  All included the pages of reviews?

Comment: all reviews + pro + con. i can pull the data from the page (i had to change the scrap time though), but pagination doesn't work. followed the tutorial for pagination but no go

Comment: Yeah pagination is tricky because you have to nest a link within itself.  I have only used that feature once so I can't honestly help.  Try https://www.httrack.com also.  It follows link structure but creates files accordingly so saving one webpage isn't bad but multiples will make it difficult to navigate.